# Android Application Not Responding Error

Tags: java, android

I twice get anr when i swipe the app from recent activities. And then the app works fine also I get an anr when I switch to landscape mode. The app works as expected as long as it is not oriented landscape or swiped from recent apps. 
Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks

MyService.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static boolean started = false;
public static String TRANSACTION_DONE = "com.example.root.project";
private WebSocketClient client = null;
public static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(started){
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if(client != null){
            client.send(message);
        }
    }

    if (!started) {
        myDataBase = openOrCreateDatabase("Messages.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDataBase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages " +
                "(tag TEXT primary key, message TEXT);");
        started = true;
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI(intent.getStringExtra("ip"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        client = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.accumulate("addme",intent.getStringExtra("name"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                client.send(jsonObject.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (jsonObject.has("resolve")) {
                    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

                    // Builds a notification
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            null;
                    try {
                        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add)
                                .setContentTitle(jsonObject.getString("name"))
                                .setTicker(jsonObject.getString("resolve"))
                                .setContentText(jsonObject.getString("destination"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Defines the Intent to fire when the notification is clicked
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);

                    // Set the default notification option
                    // DEFAULT_SOUND : Make sound
                    // DEFAULT_VIBRATE : Vibrate
                    // DEFAULT_LIGHTS : Use the default light notification
                    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

                    // Auto cancels the notification when clicked on in the task bar
                    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

                    // Gets a NotificationManager which is used to notify the user of the background event
                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    // Post the notification
                    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
                } else if (jsonObject.has("remove")) {

                    try {
                        String tag = jsonObject.getString("remove");
                        myDataBase.execSQL("DELETE FROM messages WHERE tag = " + tag + ";");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    if (isForeground(TRANSACTION_DONE)) {
                        Intent broadcast = new Intent(TRANSACTION_DONE);
                        broadcast.putExtra("message", message);
                        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                    }
                } else {

                    try {
                        myDataBase.execSQL("INSERT INTO messages (tag, message) VALUES ('" +
                                jsonObject.getString("tag") + "', '" + message + "');");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    if (isForeground(TRANSACTION_DONE)) {
                        Intent broadcast = new Intent(TRANSACTION_DONE);
                        broadcast.putExtra("message", message);
                        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.d("myTag", "onClose: websocket closing ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"closing websocket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        client.connect();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"closing client",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    client.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("myTag", "onDestroy: service being destroyed ");
    try {
        client.closeBlocking();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service is closing on destroy called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    return componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage);
}

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CustomAdapter adapter;
private String name;
private String ip;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.add) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        final View viewInflated = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, null);
        builder.setView(viewInflated);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Publish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                EditText editText = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle);
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.dialogDesc);
                String title = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                String desc = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.accumulate("title", title);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("desc", desc);
                    jsonObject.accumulate("name",name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra("message",jsonObject.toString());
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(MyPreferences.isFirst(this)) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        final View viewInflated = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(viewInflated);

        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Publish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                EditText editText = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.dialogName);
                EditText editText2 = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.dialogIp);
                name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                ip = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("ip", ip);
                MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("name",name).putString("ip",ip).commit();
                startService(intent);
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
                filter.addAction(MyService.TRANSACTION_DONE);
                registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (MyService.myDataBase == null) return;
                        Cursor cursor = MyService.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM messages", null);
                        int messageColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("message");
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        if (cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
                            do {
                                String message = cursor.getString(messageColumn);
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                                    adapter.add(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("desc"), jsonObject.getString("tag"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                            adapter.update();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        name = this.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name","no_name");
        ip  = this.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("ip","no_ip");
        intent.putExtra("name",name);
        intent.putExtra("ip",ip);
        startService(intent);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(MyService.TRANSACTION_DONE);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (MyService.myDataBase == null) return;
                Cursor cursor = MyService.myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM messages", null);
                int messageColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("message");
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
                    do {
                        String message = cursor.getString(messageColumn);
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
                            adapter.add(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("desc"), jsonObject.getString("tag"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    adapter.update();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (myReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        myReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
            if(jsonObject.has("remove")){
                adapter.remove(jsonObject.getString("remove"));
                adapter.update();
            }else {
                adapter.add(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("desc"), jsonObject.getString("tag"));
                adapter.update();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    };

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ListViewData> objects;

    public void add(String title, String desc, String tag) {
        objects.add(new ListViewData(title, desc, tag));
    }

    public void remove(String tag){
        for(ListViewData data : objects){
            if(data.getTag().equals(tag)){
                objects.remove(data);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        Button resolve;
        Button subscribe;
        Button unSubscribe;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        objects = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public ListViewData getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, null);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.resolve = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.resolve);
            holder.subscribe = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
            holder.unSubscribe = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.unsubscribe);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(objects.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(objects.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.resolve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                final View viewInflated = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog2, null);
                builder.setView(viewInflated);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("Publish", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        EditText editText = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.name);
                        EditText editText2 = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.destination);
                        String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                        String destination = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            jsonObject.accumulate("name", name);
                            jsonObject.accumulate("destination", destination);
                            jsonObject.accumulate("resolve",objects.get(position).getTag());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                        intent.putExtra("message",jsonObject.toString());
                        startService(intent);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }

        });
        holder.subscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String tag = objects.get(position).getTag();
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message",new JSONObject().accumulate("subscribe",tag).accumulate("name",name).toString());
                    startService(intent);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        holder.unSubscribe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String tag = objects.get(position).getTag();
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
                    intent.putExtra("message",new JSONObject().accumulate("unsubscribe",tag).accumulate("name",name).toString());
                    startService(intent);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}

}

class MyPreferences {

private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "my_preferences";

public static boolean isFirst(Context context){
    final SharedPreferences reader = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final boolean first = reader.getBoolean("is_first", true);
    if(first){
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = reader.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("is_first", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    return first;
}

}
```

Comment: Do you run this directly on your phone? Or via emulator? You can correctly debug this yourself if you're using an emulator or using your phone connected to your computer as one.

Comment: I used emulator

Comment: Android studio?
If so, this will help you debug your app: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html